# How to replace .PNGs inside a file with Hex?

Tags: image, replace, hex, png

I'm kinda new to messing with hex and I'm trying to replace a .PNG inside a file with HxD and I get a "This operation changes the file-size." error. The file I'm replacing it with is definitely smaller so it shouldn't be an issue (right?) but when viewing the PNG hex it has a much larger length than the file I'm trying to replace. I've looked around for help but can't seem to find anything so would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That message sounds like you need to add padding to the new file. Best bet would be to use 00 (null)

1. Figure out the exact size in bytes of the old file, note that down.
2. Figure out the exact size in bytes of the new file, note that down as well.
3. calculate the needed padding.
4. Open your new png file in HxD, go to the edit menu and select Insert Bytes.
5. Before you type in a number, just below that there are three options, select dec. Then type in the amount of bytes to add.
6. Leave the fill pattern as 00. When you hit okay the program will warn that you're changing the length of the file, this is okay, that is why you're using the option.
7. Save your new file using File -> Save As.

[screenshot of the Insert Bytes window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAbTK.png)

You could use HxD to get the sizes of the files, convert the hex offset to a decimal number, or do everything in hex if that suits you.